# Why AWS Classic Load Balancer Instances are OutOfService, but Auto Scale Group Shows InService and Healthy?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elb

I tried to avoid asking this question, but after struggling for hours (or days) and reading all related materials, I'm desperately turning to SO.

So, I am trying to deploy my node/react project to AWS with a (classic) load balancer and auto scaling group. I got all the individual pieces working. Somehow, the instances in load balancer always show OutOfService, although those instances are InService and Healty in the auto scaling group. Why this disconnect?

Then, I added an elastic IP to one of the instances. I ssh'd to it and then ran "npm start" manually. Now this instance shows InService and Healthy in the load balancer.

It appears to me that it's not a security group issue, but that the start up script didn't get executed. This is my script:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /home/ec2-user/projectname
npm start
```

Why not?

Some Update:

I enabled Access log for this balancer, and I got a lot of the (same) error logs. Here is one of them:

```
<Error>
    <Code>AccessDenied</Code>
    <Message>Access Denied</Message>
    <RequestId>BC0FA4BB97BA1557</RequestId>
    <HostId>r3wBXZLxJkTzm/SqcQnxEO+f9DhbtCxTLcVAn1vmllj6Dwa0xlO2psP3eEKOiuvNWY/Yb+Gt4C0=</HostId>
</Error>
```

This is not very helpful to me to figure out where the problem is. 
More confusing is that I also get this kind of error log when the instance is started manually and running, and instance status in LB is healthy.

What is denied? health checker? Who is the health checker? This is my health check setting in balancer:

```
Ping Target   HTTP:3000/
Timeout     5 seconds
Interval    30 seconds
Unhealthy threshold     2
Healthy threshold   10
```

The listener has HTTP 80 as load balance port and 3000 as instance port.

UPDATE again:

It appears to me that the real cause of the problem is that the start up script didn't run. I found a few suggestions around this problem like clear /var/lib/cloud folder or add #cloud-boothook to the top of the startup script, but nothing works for me.

UPDATE (3):

I couldn't make it work properly for me after a few days of struggle and give up now. However is a summary of what I learnt.

First off, I managed to follow up Ryan Lewis' PluralSight video and get it work as expected: Deploying to AWS with load balance and auto scaling. My project is very close to his "pizza-luvrs" project except that I'm using React front end and MongoDB. However, for some reason, I can't make it work for my own project.

My goal was to have load balancers work together with auto scaling group using a precreated AMI (with node, pm2 and my project installed). Using the below startup script with pm2, I got the server running at port 3000.

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "starting xxx..."
# restart pm2 and thus node app on reboot
crontab -l | { cat; echo "@reboot sudo pm2 start /home/ec2-user/xxx/server.js -i 0"; } | crontab -
# start the server on port 3000
pm2 start /home/ec2-user/xxx/server.js -i 0
echo "xxx started."
```

However, the instances in load balancer keeps saying "OutOfService", although the instances in auto scaling group always show InService. The most strange thing is that after I attach an Elastic IP (because my auto scaling instance is private) and SSH'd to the instance and without doing anything else, it becomes InService eventually (not always). I can then disassociate the Elastic IP and it keeps InService status. It sounds like the security group might be the cause of this problem, so I compared this with that "pizza-luvrs" project thousand times and made sure they have exactly the same setup. Still it works for his project but not for mine.

By the way, in AWS instances view, select an instance, then select the menu "Instance Settings" > "Get System Log", you can see how the instance gets started. This is how I can tell if my startup script in "user data" gets executed.

Comment: Can you share screenshot of your instances under your ELB? What is the network configuration? Public or Private instances? I Are the ELB HealthChecks getting passed? Could be a listener issue.

Comment: How are the health checks configured in Classic LB and Target groups? How is that script scheduled to run at boot?

Comment: @bgdnlp How are the health checks configured in Classic LB? It's all using the default except the path is changed from /index.html to /. How is that script scheduled to run at boot? It's part of a launch configuration as user data.

Comment: @AniruddhaRaje What do you mean by "What is the network configuration"? My instances are private. Are the ELB HealthChecks getting passed? That's actually my question too.

Comment: How are you executing the startup script ?

Comment: @Ankit when you create the Launch Configuration in aws, you can specify the startup script as "user data".

Answer (score 0):

What you put in [user data is executed once, on first boot](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/user-data.html#user-data-shell-scripts), that's it. It's intended for setting up the instance the first time it's started. On subsequent startups it will not run. if you want to schedule a script to run on boot look up how to do it on whatever OS you're using.

Assuming you run some form of Linux that uses systemd, which is the most popular choice, have a look [here](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=systemd+shell+script+on+boot&t=h_&ia=web&iax=qa)

You can also [execute user data on every boot](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/execute-user-data-ec2/), but it's really not worth the trouble.

Comment: Thank you very much! After trying to make it work in past few days, I desperately give it up now.